# Hello ListView Tutorial Problem

Tags: android

I am having a couple problems with the code from the tutorial: [ListView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html). The code snipets giving me problems are:

```
static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
```

and

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((View) view).getText(),
```

The errors read the following respectively:

- Illegal modifier for parameter COUNTRIES; only final is permitted
- The method getText() is undefined for the type View

I'm not really sure what to do to resolve them. I am very new to Java and Android programming so please explain it in detail. I would put the entire project in here but I am not quite sure how to package it and put it on here. (Like I said, I'm a Newbie). Thanks in advance.

```
package com.android.hellolistview;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, TextView view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
    }

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
  static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
        "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
        "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
        "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
        "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
        "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
        "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
        "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
        "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
        "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
        "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
        "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
        "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
        "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
        "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
        "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
        "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
        "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
        "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
        "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
        "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
        "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
        "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
        "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
        "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
        "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
        "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
        "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
        "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
        "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
        "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
        "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
        "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
        "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
        "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
        "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
        "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
        "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
        "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
        "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
        "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
      };}
```

Comment: Where are you placing the COUNTRIES String array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((View) view).getText()
```

Should be

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText()
```

The View class does not implement a getText method, while TextView extends View and implements the getText method.   In your code you are casting the View to a view, which really isn't doing anything.  It needs to be casted to a TextView to work properly.

I'm thinking you may be placing your `COUNTRIES` String array in the wrong place also.

Paste all your `HelloListView` code in your question if you still can't fix it.

Also, this might be a good read for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: Great thanks. I moved the Countries below where I called it and there were no errors. However when I load it into the emulator and the app runs it is a blank screen. What do you think? I add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with the emulator. I got the "application has stopped unexpectedly..." message.

I had the same line as you:

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
```

In my HelloListView Manifest I had the following line:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloListViewActivity"
```

As I changed it into:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloListView"
```

the application started working in the emulator. Renaming the class to HelloListViewActivity might also do the same trick. Didn't try that yet...

Answer (score 0):

view has not the method getText(), TextView has the method getText(), TextView extends View,
so you code must like:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText());
```

you must read the api of android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the array should be after the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Change this: public class HelloListView extends Activity{
 to: public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
and add:
view source
print?

```
1   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
2   import android.app.ListActivity;
```